# Why do I get 404 error with basic Flask code?

Tags: python, flask

My code

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify 

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/api') 
def my_microservice(): 
    return jsonify({'Hello': 'World!'}) 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run()
```

Terminal output

```
python flask_basic.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2018 14:14:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I have checked with lsof -i:5000 command and got nothing.

Why?

Comment: Because your route is `/api` and you send the request to `/` ?

Comment: Yes,thanks,works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the route to `/api` (`@app.route('/api')`), yet you sent the request to `/`: `"GET / HTTP/1.1"`.

Either change the route to `/` or send the request to `/api`